# how to target specific section when i use javaScript Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax, fixed

I'm trying to get a cool parallax effect using vanilla java script, but whenever I scroll down, all the sections with the parallax start at the same time. What I really need is for them to start when I reach the exact section, not when I scroll down. Please help, I'm a noob when it comes to javascript. I took this code from codepen from Gary Simon Design course, but I couldn't do it right, so I need help. thats what i've done so far .

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

const target = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll, .scroll2');

var index = 0, length = target.length;
for (index; index < length; index++) {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.rate;

    if(target[index].dataset.direction === 'vertical') {
        target[index].style.transform = 'translate3d(0px,'+pos+'px, 0px)';
    } else {
        var posX = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.ratex;
        var posY = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.ratey;
        
        target[index].style.transform = 'translate3d('+posX+'px, '+posY+'px, 0px)';
    }
}

});
```

```css
     body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: bold;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section .sec {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sec ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: middle;
    place-items: center;
    min-height: 120vh;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: middle;
    place-items: center;
    height: 50vh;
}

.bg-0{
    background-image: url(./images/section.jpg);
    background-color: blue;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Elena</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" integrity="sha512-OTcub78R3msOCtY3Tc6FzeDJ8N9qvQn1Ph49ou13xgA9VsH9+LRxoFU6EqLhW4+PKRfU+/HReXmSZXHEkpYoOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li class="scroll" data-rate="-2" data-direction="vertical">par</li>
                <li>al</li>
                <li class="scroll" data-rate="2" data-direction="vertical">lax</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-0">

   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <section class="sec">
        <ul>
            <li class="scroll2" data-rate="-2" data-direction="vertical">par</li>
            <li>al</li>
            <li class="scroll2" data-rate="2" data-direction="vertical">lax</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
       <p class="text-dark fs-5">rovident nisi similique eos. Nam, rerum assumenda incidunt quo illum sunt impedit! Maxime, culpa fugiat? Dolores architecto, nisi nostrum officiis aut distinctio quam fugit at, saepe, cumque quae debitis? Eligendi praesentium, iusto eaque asperiores neque laudantium qui. Provident cumque aut libero mollitia debitis sed illum, in quos repellat, illo soluta. Numquam dolores tempore ea reprehenderit deleniti, possimus unde sed vel distinctio corrupti, ex commodi labore. Voluptas eum deleniti natus modi illo repellat harum enim esse at sunt. Impedit quasi iste consectetur earum explicabo ut quod odit. Iste, deleniti repellendus! Ipsam, possimus? Quaerat eaque suscipit facere labore obcaecati beatae, sequi dolor enim quae similique. Aliquam minima expedita, aliquid veniam recusandae sequi possimus itaque, dignissimos exercitationem ipsam voluptate! Voluptatum optio dolore, ipsum atque repellat odit nulla repellendus suscipit, aperiam cum, fugit ducimus. Veniam labore dignissimos deserunt aliquid iure accusamus optio ducimus expedita sunt earum doloremque voluptatibus aperiam dolore, unde odit excepturi delectus? Porro corrupti totam quod recusandae, ipsa dolores fugit rem natus ratione et aspernatur deserunt facere. Ad delectus fugit, iure accusantium saepe minus velit dicta cumque fugiat illum! Unde recusandae exercitationem nemo temporibus? Labore totam necessitatibus natus sunt at ipsum! Nam.</p> 
       <br>
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```